# Why is the output order different when I use fetch and when I use Promise.resolve?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

In this case:

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("res1");
    return new Promise((res) => res(1));
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });

fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("res2");
    return new Promise((res) => res(2));
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });

fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("res3");
    return new Promise((res) => res(3));
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

The output is (i understand that the order here will depend on when it came first)

res1
1

res3
3

res2
2

But in this case:

```
Promise.resolve(1)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(res + " " + "first"));
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });

Promise.resolve(2)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(res + " " + "second"));
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });

Promise.resolve(3)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(res + " " + "third"));
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

I'm getting the order I've been waiting for

1

2

3

1 first

2 second

3 third

My question is why with fetch the order will always be result + immediately next then and so on

And in common Promise.resolve I have 3 results and after next 3 then

Comment: You should not rely on the order being anything in particular.

Answer (score 0):

`then` gets called when the associated promise resolves and the event loop isn't busy doing something else.

`Promise.resolve(2)` resolves immediately.

`fetch` takes time to receive the response over the network.

Comment: Thx! The main point for me was that once a promise is ready, the .then/catch/finally handlers are placed in a queue but without executing.